# multiple patterns in same conf file not working

Tags: indexing, logstash, elk

i am unable to create index using multiple groks in same file please help

```
   #request       "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date_time},%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}\s*\[\s*%{DATA:servicedetail}\s*\]\s*%{NUMBER:refid:int}\s*---\s*\[\s*%{DATA:thread}\s*\]\s*,\s*\s\"Title\"\:\"%{DATA:Title}\",\s*\"RequestId\"\:\"%{DATA:RequestId}\",\s*\"API\"\:\"%{DATA:API}\",\s*\"ApiURL\"\:\"%{DATA:ApiURL}\",\s*\"detailedMessage\":\{"%{DATA:detailedMessage}\"\{\s*\"username\"\:\"%{DATA:username}\",\s*\"password\"\:\"%{DATA:password}\",\s*\"Bank_Mnemonic\"\:\"%{DATA:Bank_Mnemonic}\",\s*\"Consumer_number\"\:\"%{DATA:Consumer_number}\",\s*\"Tran_Auth_Id\"\:\"%{NUMBER:Tran_Auth_Id}\",\s*\"Transaction_Amount\"\:\"%{NUMBER:Transaction_Amount}\",\s*\"Tran_Date\"\:\"%{NUMBER:Tran_Date}\",\s*\"Tran_Time\"\:\"%{NUMBER:Tran_Time}\",\s*\"Reserved\"\:\"%{DATA:Reserved}\"",

 #Response         "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date_time},%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}\s*\[\s*%{DATA:servicedetail}\s*\]\s*%{NUMBER:refid:int}\s*---\s*\[\s*%{DATA:thread}\s*\],\s*\s\"Title\"\:\"%{DATA:Title}\",\s*\"RequestId\"\:\"%{DATA:RequestId}\",\s*\"API\"\:\"%{DATA:API}\",\s*\"ApiURL\"\:\"%{DATA:ApiURL}\",\s*\"detailedMessage\":\{"%{DATA:detailedMessage}\:\{\"Response_code\":\"%{NUMBER:Response_code:INT}\",\s*\"Identification_Parameter\":\"%{DATA:Identification_Parameter}\",\s*\"Reserved\":\"%{DATA:Reserved}\""
```

below are the logs

REQUEST :>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

`    2021-06-25 14:53:50.078,INFO [CASHIN,ff742d4fd5ea5ed0,ff742d4fd5ea5ed0,true] 3175 --- [http-nio-8383-exec-9] , "Title":"Request", "RequestId":"86e29454-7799-4e32-8640-22d4b48b7fd9", "API":"BillPayment", "ApiURL":"CashIn/BillPayment", "detailedMessage":{"BillPayment"{"username":"2RucXgyG8KO3nKx5d2mnfgSzO9rPMei6LM4Pipi/TVZgjn/sxs4ru1q6uyc9ECNoWlo","password":"BDaFalMF5C8o1LgQEsPmpBSgOqc8bpwCs7YmPdq4ZW2YZs=","Bank_Mnemonic":"PARKRT01","Consumer_number":"923240045677","Tran_Auth_Id":"456460","Transaction_Amount":"0000020000000","Tran_Date":"20200211","Tran_Time":"091546","Reserved":""}}

RESPONSE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.

2021-06-25 14:53:50.078,INFO [CASHIN,ff742d4fd5ea5ed0,ff742d4fd5ea5ed0,true] 3175 --- [http-nio-8383-exec-9] , "Title":"Response","RequestId":"d9dd1f2a-b87e-4928-ab43-b8bfb293f2d0","API":"BillPayment","ApiURL":"CashIn/BillPayment","detailedMessage":{"GetBillPaymentRes":{"Response_code":"03","Identification_Parameter":"","Reserved":""}}    `

Comment: logs are given above by which groks are created and they are working fine in simulator  :

Comment: Please update your question with the actual patterns you are using in grok. Neither of the ones you show will compile.

Comment: i have shared the actual patterns after # request is request logs patterns and for response shared after that

Comment: also logs are attached below from which patterns are created , in groks debugger they are working fine but in actual index is not creating

Comment: A pipeline using those patterns cannot even start because there are unescaped double quotes at `\"detailedMessage\":\{"%{DATA:detailedMessage}\"`. You need to escape the quotes, not the brace. Also you have `,\s*\s\ ` in the second pattern which should probably be `\s*,\s`.

Comment: for second pattern as per logs "[http-nio-8383-exec-9] , "Title":"Response", there is space between "[http-nio-8383-exec-9] ," and " "Title":"Response" this is the reason i use \s*\s and same as of above first pattern ....request logs are for 1st pattern and response logs are for 2nd pattern .. if you please help me to recreate the patterns with the logs shared above

Comment: You say "same as of above first pattern" but they are not the same. That's the point.